Where are Next.js Server Actions executed
Where and how are Next.js Server Actions actually executed? The docs just say "the server".
I am specifically asking about Next.js Server Actions (using the app router) not router handlers in the /api folder.

Are Server Actions executed on the Next.js node server?
What about when deployed to Vercel, are Server Actions executed on the Next.js node server or extracted to "edge functions"?
Is this configurable?

I deployed a test application to Vercel that uses Server Actions. I noticed in the "Functions" admin panel that there is a index.rsc function:

The file extension, .rsc suggests "React Server Component" and leads me to believe that the entire page component function, and not just the Server Actions, (see screenshot of file system) is extracted automatically to an edge function:


Clarify further, I want to know if my Server Action is executing on the Next.js node server with the rest of the application, or in a separate lambda when deployed to Vercel. It impacts architecture planning because I expect to call my server action a lot.

This question is related to React fundamentals, I suggest you read these articles and then the answer:

Server and Client side components architecture

What is happening behind a scene when I use Server Action?
when you write a server action, it will use the server environment and render a RSC file on the server as you mentioned (React Server Component Payload) and send it to the user browser. This file is the rendered server result and is responsible for interacting and updating the DOM for the user's browser for example:
imagine a scenario where a user likes a post,

javascript increases the values of likes (without sending a request to server)
POST request will be send to the server
server invokes an RSC file (with the result of succeeding of updating like value in the database)
RSC file will tell the client that there was no problem with updating the database so keep the heart button still red.

overall RSC file is responsible for updating and interacting with the DOM based on the results from the server. and the actions.ts file is a function running on the server that triggers the RSC file which exists on the client browser.
